# Java: Make a cast which is necessary at runtime, but not at compile-time

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle

This is based on a very unusual behaviour of Java I recently found while implementing a personal project. It requires a very good understanding of Java and some knowledge of its standard library, and might even need some digging in the JLS or even JVMS.

---

Usually in Java, adding a cast can only fix compile-time problems. At runtime, adding a cast can only result in more exceptions (namely `ClassCastException`s), not less. However, there is an exception <sup><sub>no pun intended</sub></sup> to this rule, and it's your job to find it.

Concretely, implement the method `receiver` in the following Java program, such that the program compiles and prints `hello` without throwing any (uncaught) exceptions. When removing or commenting out the cast to `String` in the `main` method (without making any other changes), the program should still compile, but crash with an uncaught exception and not print anything except the exception's stack trace.

```
public class CastNecessaryAtRuntimePuzzle
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        handle((String) (ChangesAllowed.receiver().get()));
    }

    static void handle(Object value)
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    class ChangesAllowed
    {
        static AnyReturnType receiver() throws Exception
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that the casted expression is parenthesized is not relevant, it's just to make precedence clear. Also, access modifiers (`public`, `private`) aren't relevant for solving this.

This has been tested on Java 19, but should work on later versions as well. For now, I won't reveal the minimum Java version required, because it might be a hint. (EDIT: The minimum Java version is now revealed in one of the hints.)

Rules:

- You may add your own imports.
- Apart from imports, you may only change the body of the class `ChangesAllowed`. This includes the return type and body of the `receiver()` method.
- You may create own classes as inner classes of `ChangesAllowed`. Anonymous classes are allowed as well, but obviously only in methods in `ChangesAllowed` or its nested classes.

There are no tricks. This is not a challenge to find the loophole; this challenge is really solvable the way it is posed. Some examples of forbidden loopholes follow:

- Your solution may not use any kind of introspection like reading the program's source code (or class file) to find out whether the cast exists or not, and act differently according to that information.
- The main method given here must be the main method invoked by the JVM; you may not add your own main method and invoke that instead.
- Your solution may not depend on bugs - neither in the compiler, nor in the JVM.
- Your solution may not use Unicode magic to cause parts of the program outside of `ChangesAllowed` to change - this includes things like RTL override attacks etc.
- Your solution may not use `sun.misc.Unsafe` or `jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe`.
- Similarily, you may not use java agents, the JVM's debug interface or similar. (The reason fo this is that if this would be allowed, this could be used in various ways: to cause a different version of the given `main` method to be executed, or create a subclass of `String`, or change the class `String` in any way.)
- Your solution may not depend on a certain JVM implementation - especially not your own, custom JVM written for this puzzle. This has to work at least on Oracle's HotSpot JVM.
- Your solution may not depend on certain JVM options, especially not `-XX:UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`. On the HotSpot JVM, this has to work without any extra options.
- Your solution may not use any tricks to get an object of one type into a variable of an incompatible type - this would be possible with `Unsafe` or JVM bugs, but neither are allowed.

---

Hints:

> As far as I can tell, this should be possible since Java <s>9</s> 16.

> Finding the correct return type is almost all of the work - if you know the return type, creating a usable value of that type is kind of straightforward.

> The name of the method `get` called on the result of `receiver()` is very important! In fact, there's only a handful of method names which I could have used instead of `get`. The challenge is not solvable with *any* other method name! (Concretely, there are 5 names which don't require other changes, and further 27 method names which would require some more changes to the challenge, if I counted correctly.)

> No generics whatsoever are involved in the solution.

> The thrown exception won't be a `ClassCastException` - howver, I don't yet reveal the real exception type because it would make the challenge very easy.

> There is exactly one correct return type, and that is a class from the JRE - specifically, the `java.base` module. This class is the *only* return type with which this challenge can be solved - it's not possible to solve this with an own class as the return type.

---

If this kind of puzzle isn't welcome here, feel free to close as off-topic. However, it seems to fit worse on codegolf.stackexchange.com: That community frowns upon language-specific challenges or challenges where people can't compete, and this puzzle is both. Also, stackoverflow.com isn't meant for puzzles either - they recommend puzzling.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: This one is damn tricky :P

Comment: I love computer puzzles, but this one seems a little too specific to the Java language, so not sure if it fits in this community.

Comment: This has to be something about overloaded methods which are only distinguished by their return type, and the cast on the method call forces the compiler to choose one overload where it would choose another overload if the cast were not present.

Comment: @codewarrior0 Bonus hint: This is not about overloaded methods - in fact, according to the JLS, what happens with the return value of a method will not be used in determining which method is to be invoked: `When a method is invoked, the number of actual arguments [...] and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked.`, from Java 20's JLS 8.4.9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9

Comment: This puzzle seems to be _way_ harder than I thought! Tomorrow, I'll post some hints which'll make this pretty easy (I think). Specifically, I'll reveal the things mentioned in hints #3 and #5.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to narrow down the behavior. Read through the entire JLS and JVMS looking for weirdness? Examine every method named `get()` that shows up in IntelliJ? No thanks. The JDK 9 release notes at least gave me a clue about which parts of the JLS to read, which lead me to find out that the *invocation type* of a method call does in fact include the return type, which might lead to a method being dispatched differently when it is called in a different context... but I haven't been able to find anything concrete leading from there or get something working in JDoodle.

Comment: Well, it seems I greatly underestimated how hard it is to find the relevant part of the JRE / the JLS / the JVMS, using the information given here. However, I think there are better ways than to search every occurrence of `get()`, or comb through the entire JLS - there are some educated guesses one can think of on where to look. As I said, tomorrow I'll post some more hints - they'll make it obvious where to look (I hope).

Comment: Is it possible to solve this puzzle without adding any imports? That is, can I get the same behavior by implementing my own classes?

Comment: No, it has to be a certain class from the JRE - that's what I was trying to say with the last hint. I'll edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A (the?) solution:

> ```
> import java.lang.invoke.*;
>
> public class CastNecessaryAtRuntimePuzzle
> {
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
>     {
>         handle((String) (ChangesAllowed.receiver().get()));
>     }
>
>     static void handle(Object value)
>     {
>         System.out.println(value);
>     }
>
>     class ChangesAllowed
>     {
>         static String s = "Hello, World!";
>
>         static VarHandle receiver() throws Exception
>         {
>             return MethodHandles.lookup().findStaticVarHandle(ChangesAllowed.class, "s", String.class).withInvokeExactBehavior();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comments:

> [`VarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html)'s [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#get(java.lang.Object...)) (and other methods of `VarHandle` and `MethodHandle`) are very special methods called "signature polymorphic methods" (see e.g. [here in JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3) and [here in JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.3)). As I understand, this basically means the compiler will determine the argument and return types of the call to `get` based on the context where it is called. Hence, the cast to `String` will make it compile a call to a method with return type `String` whereas if there is no cast it will compile a call to a method with return type `Object`. The `VarHandle` I return is bound to the `static` `String` variable `s`. Normally, the system is permissive enough that this will still work with or without the cast, but [`withInvokeExactBehavior`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#withInvokeExactBehavior()) forces the signature to match exactly which, I guess, in the case of a `VarHandle` means the return type of `get` has to exactly match the bound field's type. Otherwise, it will throw `WrongMethodTypeException`. However, note that `withInvokeExactBehavior` seems to be from Java 16, so maybe this is not what OP was thinking of. I'm not sure how to get an error from `VarHandle` otherwise. (But, a construction with `MethodHandle` is probably possible of making a similarly meaningful cast much earlier, but may not lend itself to this kind of puzzle presentation.) ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) can run Java 20 online.)

Comment: Yep, that's the exactly the solution I had in mind! And I totally missed that <the thing> is from Java 16; I'll edit the question.

Comment: By the way, how did you find this?

Comment: I was thinking about this for a while, but didn't find/notice anything about signature polymorphism or this type, but after the last hints, I was looking at [this list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index-files/index-1.html) for methods of the right parameters. That sounds like I would find the type easily but somehow I followed the link from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) instead. Never seen it before so it took a bit to figure out what it was all about, but it quickly looked promising.